# Behaviour in Release Build I cant understand

Tags: c++, boost

While trying to find out a problem that occurs only in a release build and not in the debug build I noticed the following behaviour (String would be invalid and would not point to anything while the int would be fine). I have given code below which gives an idea of what I was going through

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> shared_cls
typedef std::deque<shared_cls> vector_def;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<vector_def> shared_vector_def;
typedef boost::unordered_map<int,shared_vector_def> inner_map_def;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<inner_map_def> shared_inner_map_def;
static boost::unordered_map<std::string,shared_inner_map_def> bcontainer;

shared_cls& SomeMethod(const std::string& symb,const int& no)
{
  shared_inner_map_def tshare = bcontainer[symb];
  shared_vector_def tmp = tshare->at(no);
  shared_cls t =  tmp->back();
  return t
}
```

The object MyClass looks like this

```
        class SomeClass
        {
           private:
           int i;
           std::string s;
           void set_i(int rx)
           {
             i = rx;
           }
           int get_i()
           {
              return i;
           }
           void set_s(std::string rx)
           {
             s = rx;
           }
           std::string get_s()
           {
              return s;
           }
        }
```

Now when I use the above method as in the following code

```
void main()
{
   shared_cls r = SomeMethod("IBM",12);
   //Here r does not have a valid string s
   //However it does have a valid int i
}
```

Now my question is in the above `main` when I call the `SomeMethod` the r returned does not have a valid string `s`. It has a scrambled value I found this out by using a logger. However the value of `s` is totally find during the function `SomeMethod`. I resolved this issue by not returning the shared pointer by reference.In that case it works. Why does removing the reference make it work

Comment: You should get a big bold warning from any decent compiler when you try to return a reference to a temporary object!

Comment: Doesnt that pointer point to an object that is present in a static container.

Comment: @MistyD, it seems that your posted code is not complete

Comment: @MistyD: the shared pointer may have pointed to an object in a static container.  But that doesn't matter. Once the function returns the shared pointer doesn't exist at all, so the reference to *it* is invalid. It doesn't matter whether or not the object that was pointed to is still valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shared_cls t`  goes out of scope because it is defined in the function `SomeMethod` itself. You need to return shared pointers by value if they are defined in the scope. In the [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/), it is explained why it is dangerous to return the reference of a temporary object.

In the case of std::string, string has a reference counting mechanism and when it's reference is decremented to zero, it becomes invalidated and a segmentation fault may be observed in such a case. Even if member `int i` is returned properly, it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: So why would the int value be there and only the string is corrupted ?

Comment: Because of undefined behavior.